# Number of rows in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I deleted rows in a table, how do I find the number of rows from 3 days ago in Oracle

Comment: You restore the backup from 3 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

3 days ago, run:

```
    Select count(*) from table;
```

Or hope that you're running 12c and have total recall enabled for this table.

Answer (score 0):

Take the number of rows in the table now, add in the number of rows you deleted and subtract the number of rows you have added since the delete.

If you are lucky, you might finds these numbers in ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS. If the stats have been gathered since, then you'll be less lucky.

Answer (score 0):

If flashback is enabled, try with

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM your_table
  AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP ('03.06.2019 08:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

(why 03.06.2019? It is "3 days ago" as today is 06.06.2019 :))

---

For example: I have a table which contains some rows:

```
SQL> select count(*) from test;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       873

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

What time is it now?

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
06.06.2019 08:43:56
```

Now, deleting some rows:

```
SQL> delete from test where evbr > 9000;

84 rows deleted.
```

Number of rows currently in a table:

```
SQL> select count(*) from test;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       789
```

How many rows were there at a certain point of time (note that I marked time before deleting those rows; it was 06.06.2019 08:43:56):

```
SQL> select count(*) from test
  2  as of timestamp to_timestamp('06.06.2019 08:43:56', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');

  COUNT(*)
----------
       873

SQL>
```